# showing ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'naveen'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in ubuntu 16.04 ?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

It shows error when trying to execute command mysql on terminal.
but it works for sudo mysql, and not showing any error message for it. i tried reinstalling mysql. but still the problem is there. hence i can't able to access the root account.

Comment: its clearly showing your credentials are wrong, user or password

Answer (score 0):

Try typing **sudo mysql --default-auth=mysql_native_password** in terminal.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/native-pluggable-authentication.html

**OR**

mysql -u {{ your username }} -p